# Converting an int to an unsigned char in C

Tags: c, casting, unsigned-char

I've never needed to use unsigned char before, but I've recently became curious about their ability to store integers. Through a little bit of reading I have done I've found that the cast from int to unsigned char is done implicitly, but I have also explicitly added the cast. Either way, the code below does not work and either prints out the alphabet letter equivalent or a small empty box.

```
printf("%s", "Number: ");
int input;
scanf("%d", &input);  
unsigned char num = input;
printf("%c%s%d", num, " = ", input);
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Comment: It will print the equivalent alphabet until you overflow it, in this case in prints nothing just like 0.

Comment: use `%hhu` instead of `%c`. (if you use MSVC, use `%u`)

Answer (score 1):

You are printing out the number as a *character* (`%c`) instead of an *integer* (`%hhu`).

Answer (score 1):

In `printf`, the `%c` means to print the character symbol whose code is the corresponding argument.

To print the numeric value use `%d` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It prints a letter because you set `printf()` to print num's value as a character with `"%c"`. If you use `"%d"` for example you can print its numeric value.